# Mathematica list will not populate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

NOTE: I am not a Mathematica programmer, but for a class I need to write expressions in it. I understand it is a functional language unlike C or Java.

I am trying to 'compare' (I use that for lack of a better term) the indexes or two irrational numbers. I then try to store whether or not they are equal, 1 and 0 respectively, in a list. Though, the comparison list is not populated (OUTPUT = "{}")

What is wrong with my logic in the for loop (aside from being non-functionally programed and inefficient)

```
piDigits = RealDigits[N[Pi, 15000000]]
rootDigits = RealDigits[N[Sqrt[2],15000000]] 

comparisonList = List[]

For[i = 1, i < Length[Part[piDigits, 0]], i++, 
  If[Part[piDigits, i] == Part[rootDigits, i] , 
    Append[comparisonList, 1], Append[comparisonList, 0]]]

comparisonList
```

Comment: First off [don't use `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134610/38205) second Mathematica data structures are immutable and thus you must use `AppendTo`. `Append` creates a new structure.

Comment: It's extremely likely that this expression - `Part[piDigits, 0]` - doesn't produce the result you think it does.  Go on, try it in isolation.